What is the purpose of R1, D1 in this gate driver? How they can control the turn on/off time?
I'm  reading the datasheet for the ZXGD3004E6 gate driver. I don't understand why R1 and D1 are there.


R1 is there to control the turn ON time of the FET. This could be because of EMC issues if you have too abrupt current spikes or simply to limit the inrush peak current.
The diode is there to discharge the FET as quickly as possible. You can control the turn ON/OFF time with in the same branch with only two components.
The component size for the resistor depends onif you switch your load at a frequency (ON/OFF.) Then it is a compromise between inrush current, EMI which is higher at lower resistance and switching losses which is higher at higher resistances.
The resistance is usually between 10 to 100 ohm, but is also dependent on the input capacitance of the FET.
If you also want to control the OFF time then you can also insert a resistance in series with the diode.
